# Vue transition not displaying on set height/width

Tags: vue.js

So I have what looks to me like a pretty bog-standard setup:

```
<template>
    <transition name='expand'>
        <div id='menu' v-if='open'>...</div>
    </transition>
</template>

<style>
#menu {
    height: 25rem;
    width: 25rem;
    ...
}

.expand-enter-active {
    transition: height 0.25s ease-out, width 0.25s ease-out;
}

.expand-enter {
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
}
</style>
```

And yet, there's no transition. The 3rem box can be seen for a brief frame and then it jumps to fully expanded. If I try the transition with opacity, it works as expected, but height and width properties do not...

Comment: try setting height width to parent

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: `<transition>` is parent to `<div>`, if you will set height width to child will automatically be of that height and width

Comment: Nope... Setting the value of #topmenu to parent causes the box to just stay at 3rem, putting styling on `<transition` does not change that.